# Ckeckbox check works when clicked on label only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I need to change the value of the checkbox whether it's checked or not for error validation purposes.

The setup is like this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  function toggle_checkbox_value(e) {
    var $this = $(e.currentTarget);
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$this.data('lockedAt') || +new Date() - $this.data('lockedAt') > 300) {
      var $input_terms = $('#terms');

      if ($input_terms.val() == '0') {
        $input_terms.val('1');
        $input_terms[0].checked = true;
      } else {
        $input_terms.val('0');
        $input_terms[0].checked = false;
      }
    }
    $this.data('lockedAt', +new Date());
  }

  $(document).on('click', 'label[for="terms"]', toggle_checkbox_value)
    .on('click', '#terms', toggle_checkbox_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="terms" type="checkbox" name="terms" value="0">
<label for="terms" class="checkbox">I've read and accept the terms &amp; conditions</label>
```

I've tried with `.attr('checked', 'checked')` and with `.prop('checked', true)` but nothing I did seems to work.

When I click on label, the checkbox will be checked (check mark shown), but when I click on the checkbox, the value changes in DOM when I inspect it, but the check mark is not shown.

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: remove    e.preventDefault(); - it _prevents the default action_ which is to check the box.

Comment: This enables checkbox, but when I click on label I'm not getting checkbox checked :D

Comment: What is the point of this whole scenario, you also have `  $input_terms[0].checked = false;` which is not making sense

Comment: Well I want to check the checkbox input and change its value depending whether it's checked or not. Should be easy, but I'm making some silly mistake and I'm not seeing it :S

Comment: the label is connected to the checkbox via the "for" attribute anyway, on DOM level; there should be no need to bind an event to the _label_.

Comment: WHAT is the purpose of the code?

Comment: @dlatikay I know that they are, but the value isn't changing. The purpose is to change the value on the `<input type="checkbox" value=0 />` from 0 to 1 - 0 when not checked, 1 when it is checked...

Comment: cause I think the .on('click') bound to the label will double-trigger the nested onclick event. bind just to the checkbox.

Comment: offtopic: your `$this` may apply to *either* the label or the tickbox - so checking `lockedAt` will have two different values depending on which you click.  I suggest you refactor.

Comment: Don't set the value of the tickbox in the tickbox event handler - instead, check your `lockedAt` and then call `e.preventDefault` only if you don't want the tickbox to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. But this will work

However your server will only retrieve the terms' value if the checkbox is checked so just test if it is set on the server

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $("#terms").on('click',function() {
    this.value=this.checked?1:0;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="terms" type="checkbox" name="terms" value="0">
<label for="terms" class="checkbox">I've read and accept the terms &amp; conditions</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is correct, but since I'm sending this as a `POST` for my ajax call, I realized that my logic is wrong in checking the errors in the php. Should just retain the original functionality of the checkbox, and fix the php code :)

Comment: Yes, that was my second suggestion :)